# Shopping cart price rule - How to make customer be able to choose which promotion they want?

Tags: sales, promotions

By default, if both **Promotion A** & **Promotion B** can be apply to cart, it will be applied automatically.

I need to custom magento shopping cart price rule to make customer be able to choose which promotion they want. In checkout cart page, customer must see 2 checkbox of **promotion A & B** to choose only one of them.

How can I do that ? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is too advanced to achieve with just the Magento shopping cart price rules. As you say you need a custom process, and to customize Magento in this way will require either an existing module, or a module specifically written to implement the functionality you want.

I would start by looking for solutions that already exist via google, or Magento connect. You might find code examples that you can use, or a free module that you can adapt to your needs.

Whilst it might sound complex to develop your own module, if you have experience with Magento and PHP development you should be able to program a solution. The solution itself is however outwith the scope of a simple answer in this forum.